# How can I externalize these play libraries

Tags: scala, sbt

I started to use a project/Settings.scala to help clean up my main build.sbt. This is a scalajs project with Play backend where I use Play's WS & Cache dependencies. In built.sbt the 'string/keyword/' <-not sure correct term here but `ws` and `cache` properly resolve. However in my `Seq[String]` in `Settings.scala` where I store my server library dependencies they won't. Currently I am using

```
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(ws, cache) ++ Settings.jvmDependencies.value,
```

which works but it makes me wonder how I might be able to move everything to Settings or if that is possible. When I dig one layer deeper in IDE I see for example ws is defined as :

```
  val ws : sbt.ModuleID = { /* compiled code */ }
```

in the object `PlayImport` but I can't see the proper values to populate a full/typical dependency definition for sbt

Ultimately I am curious can I successfully export `ws` & `cache` such that I can have this line in my build.sbt

```
 libraryDependencies ++= Settings.jvmDependencies.value,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a direct look at the Play SBT plugin sources, it's usually the easiest way. Here's how the `ws` [defined](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayImport.scala#L52):

```
val ws = component("play-ahc-ws")
```

where `component` is defined in [the same file](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayImport.scala#L18) like this:

```
def component(id: String) = "com.typesafe.play" %% id % play.core.PlayVersion.current
```

With this information we know the `ws` dependency amounts to `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ahc-ws" % "2.5.10"` for the current Play version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have all the Play symbols in your plugin - which is what your `project/Settings.scala` file is - just import the fields from the Play plugin's [`autoImport` member](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/45891dac31986a901711cdc2867d224084555913/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/Play.scala#L21):

```scala
import play.sbt.Play.autoImport._
```

This will let you use `ws`, `cache`, and any other symbols the plugin exposes.